# Regex lookahead and behind?

Tags: regex

So I have a unordered list that looks like:

```
<ul class='radio' id='input_16_5'>
<li>
    <input name='input_5' type='radio' value='location_1'  id='choice_16_5_0' />
    <label for='choice_16_5_0' id='label_16_5_0'>Location 1</label></li>
<li>
    <input name='input_5' type='radio' value='location_2'  id='choice_16_5_1' />
    <label for='choice_16_5_1' id='label_16_5_1'>Location 2</label></li>
<li>
    <input name='input_5' type='radio' value='location_3'  id='choice_16_5_2' />
    <label for='choice_16_5_2' id='label_16_5_2'>Location 3</label></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to pass a value (ie. location_2) to a regular expression that will then capture the whole list item that it's a part of in order to remove it. So if I pass it `location_2` it will match the to the (including) `<li>` and the `</li>` of the list item that it's in.

I can match up to the end of the list item with `/location_3.+?(?=<li|<\/ul)/` but is there something I can do to match before and not capture other items?

Comment: I should add that I know I can do it by limiting characters from `<li>` to the value, but I don't think thats ideal. Is something like this the only way? `/<li.{1,100}location_3.+?(?=<li|<\/ul)/`

Comment: `<li>.*?location2.*?</li>`  ?

Comment: What is the programming language? You just need a DOM parser with `//li/input[@value='location_2']` XPath expression to get the `li` you are interested in.

Comment: There are situations when regex is the best tool. In many situations, regex may or may not be the best tool. There are situations, however, when regex is absolutely, undoubtedly, 100% the wrong tool. Parsing mark-up languages, such as XML and HTML, is one of such situations. **TL;DR;** Don't use regex for this task.

Comment: Actually the problem with @Tensibai solution is that it will start at the first <li> instead of the second one.

Comment: @nobig  should not, I added a ? so the match is not greedy...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight When you're just trying to "grep" a part of text, regex are  perfectly ok and usually faster than a dom parser. If you wish to extract each <li> element and then access inner elements, I agree regex is not the right tool.

Comment: Check it out here @Tensibai http://regexr.com/3bm5u

Comment: @stribizhev dom parser seems like it could be a good solution for me. Still interested to know if its possible with regex

Comment: @nobig I was checking on regex101, sounds strange it does not get a match, with an ungreedy operator it should get in (but yes it start matching at the first li and return soon)

Comment: @nobig: It is possible with some assumptions and limitations. Regex is not meant to parse huge texts, it may fail with arbitrary HTML (wild quotes, non-serialized angle brackets), etc. Only use regex with HTML if you yourself write it and you know you write it well. Or someone else you know writes it "well enough for your regex". It is rarely a case, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get what you want

```
<li>(?:(?!<li>)[\S\s])+location_1[\S\s]+?<\/li>
```

**Exaplanation**

`<li>`: open `li` tag,

`(?:(?!<li>)[\S\s])+`: match for any characters including a newline and use negative look ahead to make sure that your highlight will not consume two or more `<li>` tags,

`location_1`: keyword that you use for highlight the whole `<li>` tag,

`[\S\s]+?`: any characters including a newline. (Here, thanks @Tensibai for your comment that make this regex be more simple with non-greedy)

`<\/li>` close `li` tag.

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/cU4eC6/5

**Additional information:**

```
/<li>(?:(?!<li>).)+location_2.+?<\/li>/s
```

This regex is also work where you use modifier `s` to handle a newline instead of `[\S\s]`. (Thanks again to @Tensibai)

Comment: I tried changing it to location_2 or location_3 and it didn't quite work

Comment: @nobig Please check again I fixed it.

Comment: @Tensibai I fixed it already please check a demo. Thank you for you comment.

Comment: Still a mater of taste, But I would set an ungreedy operator instead of the negative lookahead for the last </li>

Comment: i.e. `<li>(?:(?!<li>)[\S\s])+location_2[\S\s]+?<\/li>` is OK too. However nice work with the repeated group with a neg lookahead inside.

Comment: And last one: `/<li>(?:(?!<li>).)+location_2.+?<\/li>/s` (just s modifier for single line so `.` match newlines too)